# Result of query is not collapse

Tags: sql, oracle

Can I get a little help with this.

The query goes like:

```
SELECT  
       SUBSTR(house.nr,1,3), SUM(road.quantity),
       COUNT(people.name),  goods.price*sum(road.quantity) /goods.quantity          

FROM       home, road, house, goods, people

WHERE      home.hoid = road.roid
           AND home.hrid = house.nrid
           AND road.gdsid = goods.goodsid
           AND goods.nmid = people.nameid

GROUP BY   SUBSTR(nr,1,3), people.name, goods.price, road.quantity, goods.quantity

ORDER BY   SUBSTR(nr,1,3)
```

[image: This is what I get]

[image: This is what I want]

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: What do these images represent? The actual data you're getting and the needed result?

Comment: Top one is the output to the query the one bellow is what I want to get.

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by name, price, and quantity, so the result will contain one row for each value.  Instead select the aggregates and group by the first column:

```
SELECT  
   SUBSTR(house.nr,1,3), SUM(road.quantity), COUNT(people.name),
   SUM(goods.price*sum(road.quantity) /goods.quantity) AS price
...
GROUP BY SUBSTR(house.nr,1,3)
```

Comment: Grouping by a value that is the result of an aggregate (which in turn requires a group by) doesn't make sense to me. He only wants (needs) `group by SUBSTR(house.nr,1,3)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually now that I'm thinking more about it I think you are right and it should work just group by `SUBSTR(house.nr,1,3)`. Editing my answer.

Comment: hi adding the `GROUP BY SUBSTR(house.nr,1,3)` and `SUM(goods.price*sum(road.quantity) /goods.quantity) AS price`  return: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function